# c# WPF spell checker for misspelled word strings.

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I am looking for ways to automatically fix a word if the word is miss spelled and seems to be a combination of two words. For example "considerationof" should be "consideration of".  Any lead or any example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF?...

Comment: Have you seen this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is more than a certain degree of irony in this question. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/misspelled

Comment: Thanks Brad, I did see that while I was searching the web. Do you know how I would auto correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for iterating over your spelling mistakes:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
tb.Text = @"I am looking for ways to automatically fix a word if the word is miss spelled and seems to be a combination of two words. For example ""considerationof"" should be ""consideration of"". Any lead or any example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!";

var spellingErrorIndex = tb.Text.Length;
do
{

    var spellingError = tb.GetSpellingError(spellingErrorIndex);
    if (spellingError != null)
    {
        var suggestions = spellingError.Suggestions;    //suggests "consideration of"
        spellingError.Correct(suggestions.First());
    }

    spellingErrorIndex = tb.GetNextSpellingErrorCharacterIndex(spellingErrorIndex, LogicalDirection.Backward);
} while (spellingErrorIndex >= 0);
```

The value of `tb.Text` after this is run is

> "I am looking for ways to automatically fix a word if the word is miss spelled and seems to be a combination of two words. For example \"consideration of\" should be \"consideration of\". Any lead or any example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!"

It "auto-corrects" to the first suggestion. Whether that is ultimately what you want or not you'll have to decide.

It would probably be a bad idea to put this on a `TextChanged` event (you don't want it correcting words before they've finished beign typed). Maybe something like `LostFocus` is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks this worked!.